# What markdown should I use to <cite/> a work?

Tags: support, markdown, citation

I wanted to `<cite/>` a work in my markdown on stackexchange, but I saw in the preview that this tag was filtered out. I know that people dislike using `<em/>` (`*title*`) to cite work titles because that is semantically incorrect. How am I supposed to cite a work on a stackexchange site?

Example of what happens when I try to use `<cite/>`:

```
> <cite>Chitty Chitty Bang Bang</cite> is a citable work.
```

becomes:

> Chitty Chitty Bang Bang is a citable work.

In searching for an answer to the question on my own:

1. I clicked help and got to [Markdown Editing Help](https://music.stackexchange.com/editing-help) which didn’t seem to mention `<cite/>`.
2. I followed the link to [Daring Fireball: Markdown Syntax Documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) which mentions “Span-level HTML tags — e.g. `<span>`, `<cite>`, or `<del>` — can be used anywhere in a Markdown paragraph, list item, or header. If you want, you can even use HTML tags instead of Markdown formatting”

Comment: According to the source of this post, the `<cite>` tags are still in the rendered output; there's just no special styling applied to the contents on SE. Is that a mistake? If not, I'm not completely clear on what you're asking: "What markdown should I use?" "Use `<cite>`, as you're already doing".

Comment: @JoshCaswell I see `<p>Chitty Chitty Bang Bang is a citable work.</p>`, not `<p><cite>Chitty Chitty Bang Bang</cite> is a citable work.</p>`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're trying to use HTML and not Markdown.

See the [editing help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Use the 'Quote' option in the formatting:

`> Blockquote`

(And make sure you add a link to the source where possible).

Comment: `<cite/>` is not `<blockquote/>`. It is used to mark up the title of a work being referred to, such as a well known book, etc.. See the markdown of my example.

Comment: I’ve updated my question to make my example of how `<cite/>` is being stripped more obvious

Comment: That's because there is not a 1:1 link between HTML and Markdown. Markdown is a stripped-down syntax.

Comment: No, markdown proper says HTML should be fully passed through in many instances. [I think it shouldn’t](http://talk.commonmark.org/t/remove-html-passthru-pass-through/1869). But it’s the way it is. What’s happening here is that the HTML sanitizer is stripping `<cite/>` tags for some reason. So how do I get stackexchange to emit `<cite/>` or mark it up in a way that *stackexchange* perceives as a work title reference so that it *could* decide to render that as `<cite/>` in the future?

Comment: *"It is used to mark up the title of a work being referred to"* - Italics seem perfectly fine for that then. What's the prioblem with them?

Comment: It is semantically incorrect to use italics, emphasis, bold, blockquote, strong, etc.. <cite> is semantically correct, and expected in many environments.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that people dislike using `<em/>` (`*title*`) to cite work titles because that is semantically incorrect

`<cite>` is somewhat equivalent to the italics, right? Then the direct equivalent is enclosing text in asterisks, as in your example you believe to be disliked.

The quoting option is only one: put `>` before the text you want to quote.

---

As for the thing about how it's interpreted by the browsers and search engines - no alternative in markdown and, apparently, no alternative in the [allowed HTML tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909).

Comment: `*emphasis*` outputs emphasis—`<em/>`—in markdown. See [Why a `<cite>` when I have `<em>`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2820688/429091).